# How to add this element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a program in which i need multiple accordion menu like more than 100 but only first work properly. I know this can be solved with this selector in jquery but i am very new in jquery so i have no idea how to add this element.

Accordion menu is copied from internet in which one menu is opened other already become inactive(closed). In my case only topmost menu is working properly not other

my coding
HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>

   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>

      </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
  </div>
<br><br>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>

   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>

      </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
  </div>
    <br><br>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>

   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>

      </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
  </div>
```

css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Base Styles */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding: 6px 15px;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4e53;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3e3d3c;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  background: #64676e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #64676e), color-stop(100%, #4c4e53));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  background: #97c700;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #97c700), color-stop(100%, #709400));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  color: #4e5800;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #709400;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a:after {
  right: 14px;
  top: 12px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #4e5800;
}
/* Sub menu */
#cssmenu ul ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  background: #efefef;
  display: block;
  color: #797979;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.odd a {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

jquery

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
$('#cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
  $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  }
  if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;   
  }     
});
});
} )( jQuery );
```

js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ru5L5cLg/

Comment: Why dont you use [jquery ui accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: because this has same problem too.

Comment: What problem it has?

Comment: Only first one is showing as accordion menu, all other are looking like just plain text not as menu....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');`, use `$(this).closest('#cssmenu').find('li').removeClass('active');`

Similarly instead of `$('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');`, use `$(this).closest('#cssmenu').find('ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');`

By using it like this one accordion menu will not interfere with the other one

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
        $('#cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
        $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('#cssmenu').find('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('#cssmenu').find('ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/ru5L5cLg/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Change ID to Class

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Base Styles */
.cssmenu,
.cssmenu ul,
.cssmenu li,
.cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
.cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding: 6px 15px;
}
.cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4e53;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3e3d3c;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  background: #64676e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #64676e), color-stop(100%, #4c4e53));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  background: #97c700;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #97c700), color-stop(100%, #709400));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  color: #4e5800;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #709400;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a:after {
  right: 14px;
  top: 12px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #4e5800;
}
/* Sub menu */
.cssmenu ul ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}
.cssmenu ul ul a {
  background: #efefef;
  display: block;
  color: #797979;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li.odd a {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

Jquery

```
  ( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
$('.cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
$('.cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
  $('.cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('.cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  }
  if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;   
  }     
});
});
} )( jQuery );
```

HTML

```
<div class='cssmenu'>
<ul>

   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>

      </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
  </div>
<br><br>
<div class='cssmenu'>
<ul>

   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>

      </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
  </div>
```

Link - https://jsfiddle.net/ru5L5cLg/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Base Styles */
.cssmenu,
.cssmenu ul,
.cssmenu li,
.cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
.cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding: 6px 15px;
}
.cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4e53;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3e3d3c;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  background: #64676e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #64676e), color-stop(100%, #4c4e53));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#64676e 0%, #4c4e53 100%);
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  background: #97c700;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #97c700), color-stop(100%, #709400));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#97c700 0%, #709400 100%);
  color: #4e5800;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #709400;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a:after {
  right: 14px;
  top: 12px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #4e5800;
}
/* Sub menu */
.cssmenu ul ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}
.cssmenu ul ul a {
  background: #efefef;
  display: block;
  color: #797979;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li.odd a {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}
.cssmenu ul ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/ru5L5cLg/6/)